# Can anybody explain me this code?

Tags: java-me

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class SlideImage extends MIDlet{
  private Display display;

  public void startApp(){
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    display.setCurrent(new IconsCanvas()); 
  }

  public void pauseApp(){}

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional){
    notifyDestroyed();
  }
}

class IconsCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable{
  SlideMenu menu = null;

  public IconsCanvas(){
    Image[] image = new Image[10];     
    try{
      image[0] = Image.createImage("/bollywood-height.png");
      image[1] = Image.createImage("/212229_1193669628.png");
      image[2] = Image.createImage("/95936_50.png");
      image[3] = Image.createImage("/shreya.png");
      image[4] = Image.createImage("/Aishw.png");
      image[5] = Image.createImage("/karishma.png");
      image[6] = Image.createImage("/tmb_jiahkhannishabd.png");
      image[7] = Image.createImage("/amisha.png");
      image[8] = Image.createImage("/shilpashetty.png");
      image[9] = Image.createImage("/priti.png");

      menu = new SlideMenu(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", 
      "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"},  
        image,  getWidth(),  getHeight());
      new Thread(this).start();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  protected void paint(Graphics g){
    menu.paint(g);
  }

  public void keyPressed(int key){
    int gameKey = getGameAction(key);
    if(gameKey == Canvas.RIGHT){
      menu.slideItem(1);
    }else if(gameKey == Canvas.LEFT){
      menu.slideItem(- 1);
    }
  }

  public void run(){
    try{
      while(true){
        repaint();
        synchronized(this){
          wait(100L);
        }
      }
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Most of things in this code i got the reason for usage..but the rest of things like

```
SlideMenu,
menu.paint(g),
menu.slideItem(1);
menu.slideItem(-1);
```

The above things, i find difficult to know why they have been used...

Answer (score 4):

It (your original snippet, the `run` method)  looks like a thread whose sole task it is to just repaint the component every tenth of a second.

As to what component it refers to, you haven't provided enough information. It depends on the object that the `run()` is running for.

In terms of the `synchronized` bit, this is most likely a way to prevent other threads doing stuff to the component while this thread is within the `sleep`.

If `this` is the object `xyz`, then any other thread trying to execute a block like:

```
synchronized (xyz) {
    // Work your magic here.
}
```

will not be able to run while the `wait` is progressing.

---

By the way, if you use four spaces at the start of each code line (instead of `<pre>`), you get the nice syntax colouring as well. If you just mark the entire bit of code in the editor and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, it will do it for you automagicaly.

---

And, in terms of your update, SlideMenu (picture on [this page](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/slide-menu.shtml)) appears to be a menu where one item is shown on the screen and left/right arrows allow you to scroll:

```
     +---------+
     |         |
 /   |         |   \
<    |  image  |    >
 \   |         |   /
     |         |
     +---------+
```

(forgive my pitiful graphic ability, I'll leave it there in case the link below ever disappears).

[image]

No doubt the images in the `IconsCanvas` ate the menu items to display. With that in mind, the other things make sense.

- `SlideMenu`, I've already described.
- `menu.paint(g)` is called to display the new menu in response to the `IconsCanvas` getting a paint request.
- `menu.SlideItem()` slides the menu left or right depending on the argument.
- The 100ms makes more sense now, if the image actually scrolls smoothly to the left or right.

Comment: Thanks for response pax,but my doubt is y wait(100L) is placed with in synchronized(this),what happens if it is not so?

Comment: It means any other thread that uses `sych(that)` where `that` is the component will wait until this thread has stopped waiting. It looks like a form of contention control. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Pax,i have updated the code, if u can find the flow of the code pls get back to me

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet above, on the `synchronized` block, the author's intention is just to wait/sleep so to be cooperative and let other threads run, and wait() must always be `synchronized`. But there is no need to queue so many repaints as there is no true animation going on, just displaying static slides (Images) when advancing to next/prev; the Canvas won't get invalidated until a new slide is shown (or a call comes in, etc), meaning it should be Ok to only repaint when a new slide is shown. Note that if "smooth scrolling" is desired, such effect should be implemented by `SlideMenu` itself which must also take care of repaints() scheduling (vs. `IconCanvas`)

Other comments:

- On `SlideMenu` -- need to see the implementation of it
- On `menu.paint(g)` -- it is delegating to the slide menu itself to paint/ refresh the current slide
- On `menu.slideItem(1);` / `menu.slideItem(-1);` -- without looking at `SlideMenu` it seems to be a mechanism for navigation next/previous
- You should consider making `IconCanvas` and `SlideMenu` Singletons.